# Calculate parking fee. '&' versus 'and'

Tags: python

I am trying to write a Python program that charges the parking fee for how many hours you have parked.

Everything works fine until the minutes exceed 300.

I have played with returns and every time I did that after the input I would get successful completion no output.

When I put in 600 minutes (10 hours) I get a fee of 40 dollars when it should be 30 dollars.

Here is my code:

```
import math
rate1 = 5
rate2 = 4
rate3 = 3


m = int(input('Please enter the number of minutes parked: '))

if m <= 60:
  x = m/60
  fee = math.ceil(x) * 5
  print('Parking fee for',m,'minutes is $',fee)

elif m>60 & m<=300:
  x = m/60
  fee = math.ceil(x) * rate2
  print('Parking fee for',m,'minutes is $',fee)

elif m>300:
  x = m/60
  fee = math.ceil(x) * rate3
  print('Parking fee for',m,'minutes is $',fee)

else:
  print('Invalid input')
```

output:

```
Please enter the number of minutes parked: 600
Parking fee for 600 minutes is $ 40

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You need to indent the body of `if` statements.

Comment: There is an edit pending properly indenting the body of the `if` statements. Please upvote that pending edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if m > 60 & m <= 300:
```

should be:

```
if m > 60 and m <= 300:
```

or

```
if 60 < m <= 300:
```

`&` is the bit-wise `AND` operator, `and` is the logical `AND` operator (this is analogous to the difference between `&` and `&&` in C, PHP, and Javascript).

Comment: you mean `60 < m <= 300`?

Comment: I’ll give that a try, I hope it works, the simplest things can be the hardest haha, I’ll update in 30 minutes when I get back to computer!

Comment: it worked! wow...i cant believe something so simple stumped me for 3 hours today...thank you so much Barmar!